# The field value is not Printed in SQL Reports if i use IIF Statement

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have design the SQL Reports with multiple DataSets. On that any one of the condition the DataSet will return empty. If the DataSet is empty i need to print 0 for that. I have wrote the code like blow.

```
=iif(Rownumber("DataSet6")=0,"0",Fields!RecyclePercent.Value)
```

But it is not print the O.

Pls help me to resolve this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If a tablix (table, list or matrix) is connected to a dataset that returns no rows, then the tablix will not show any data rows (detail or other group rows.)

If you would like the tablix to show rows when the dataset returns none, there are two easy answers:

1. Alter your dataset to always return a row: usually with a union.
2. Add a fake data row to your tablix header, but set the visibility of this row to an expression such as `=CountRows("DataSet6") <> 0`. This will hide the row when there are real rows returned by the dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `CountRows("DataSet6")` instead

Comment: I have use this also but now also its not printing.